# Android Endpoint project - TicTacToe example not launching

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

As I am trying to do a Endpoints connected Android project and encountered an error, I tried to launch the sample app provided by Google https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android.

I actually have the exact same error...

```
05-11 21:46:48.935: E/AndroidRuntime(744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 21:46:48.935: E/AndroidRuntime(744): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-11 21:46:48.935: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.google.api.services.tictactoe.Tictactoe$Builder.build(Tictactoe.java:474)
```

I really don't know where it can come from.

I added the libraries as written in the readme file.

Comment: thats a pretty standard message ;) are all your files in the right place and your libraries being found?

Comment: Well, I think so. I don't have any warnings. It does compile it is only at the launch of the application that I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had read the entire log that would have saved me some hours of troubles...

In fact it was a problem of version.

```
  static {
    com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkState(
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.MAJOR_VERSION == 1 &&
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.MINOR_VERSION >= 14,
        "You are currently running with version %s of google-api-client. " +
        "You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version " +
        "1.15.0-rc of the  library.", com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.VERSION);
  }
```

I changed the MINOR_VERSION from 15 to 14. It was the exact same problem with the tictactoe sample, but it was asking for exactly 13 hen I had the 13.

I checked updates and it didn't found anything to update so I don't know why it was asking me for the 15....